# Display a progressBar and use the execution time of several functions in QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis-3, pyqt

I developed a plugin under QGIS and I added a progressBar using QT Designer. Using a pushButton, I execute several functions directly in the `__init__(self, iface)` function. What I want to do is to have a real progression of function execution time and observe it in the GUI of the plugin (bar progression with percents)

Below a different function's execution :

```
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.progressBar_test)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_indiceColonnesTDJ)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.move_in_group)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_ftta)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.cheminement_carto)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_EtatDNCapillaire)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_EtatOMEGA)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_coord_cheminTrans)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_dict_coordAncrage)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.layer_fusion)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.chargement_liaisons)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_EtatMigrationPort10G)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_TDJ_5G_TypeTrans)
    self.dlg.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.recup_TDJ_5G)
```

I have tried all the suggestions to the various questions asked about this but I have not found a question that directly addresses the time elapsed while execution of different functions in the same time.

Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a variable to the first function to store starting time. For example (`self.start`). Define a new function to set progress. Then use that function instead of `setValue` in other functions called by `clicked` event of the push button.

```py
from time import time, gmtime, strftime

class class_name(...):

    def __init__(self, iface):
        ...

    def set_progress(self, progress_value):
        t = time() - self.start
        hms = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime(t))
        
        self.progressBar.setValue(progress_value)
        self.progressBar.setFormat(f"{hms} - %p%")


    # the first function called by clicked event
    def progressBar_test(self):

        self.start = time()

        ...
        self.set_progress(<Value>) # instead of self.progressBar.setValue(<Value>)
        ...

    # another function called by clicked event
    def other_function1(self):

        # use just set_progress
        self.set_progress(<Value>)
        ...
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kadir for your help, I have just one question please:  What is th parameter '<Value>' in 'self.set_progress(<Value>)'? Thank you

Comment: Value-> integer. 0, 1, 2, …, 100.